# Getting Error while Registering in php

Tags: php

please help me wile i am registering to my script please help

```
//If we have made it here without dying, then we are in the clear to 
//create a new user.  Let's setup our new query to create a user.  
//Again, to protect against sql injects, user tokens such as :user and :pass
$query = "INSERT INTO users ( username, password ) VALUES (':user,:pass') ";

//Again, we need to update our tokens with the actual data:
$query_params = array(
    ':user' => $_POST['username'],
    ':pass' => $_POST['password']
);

//time to run our query, and create the user
try {
    $stmlt = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    // For tt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $resuesting, you could use a die and message. 
    //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

    //or just use this use this one:
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}
```

Comment: This just looks like code... Have you debugged at all?

Comment: If you're getting an error, it would help no end if you included it in your question.

Comment: 1) - where do you use `$query`? 2) Where do you define `$stmt`? 3) What is `$resuesting, you could use a die and message.` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users ( username, password ) VALUES (':user,:pass') ";
```

to

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users ( username, password ) VALUES (:user, :pass) ";
```

The single quotes in `VALUES (':user,:pass')` are most likely causing your problems.

Comment: @AlkeshPurohit Try changing `$response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again!";` to `$response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again! " . $ex->getMessage();` and add the resulting error as an edit to your post.

Comment: {"success":0,"message":"Database Error2. Please Try Again! SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 3"}

Comment: @AlkeshPurohit You're probably entering the same username twice? If it is a unique column, you can't enter the same value.

Comment: @AlkeshPurohit Before you try to insert a new user, check to see if the username already exists in your table.

Comment: i dont know it i am new in php can you please came and chat with me on facebook or gmail or any were u like

Comment: Try using `VALUES (':user',':pass')` @AlkeshPurohit